# Return Image from signature with navigator.pop

Tags: android, flutter

I'm write code for signature image . but when i use packages flutter_signature_pad , and return back result , the result just blank screen .

I've tried using navigator.pop and Setinitstate like this code .

FirstScreen

```
_navigateAndDisplaySelection(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignApp()),
    );
    setState(() {
      _imageFile = result;
    });
  }
```

```
   Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 150.0,
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              _navigateAndDisplaySelection(context);
            },
            child: _imageFile == null ? Image.network(BaseURL.folderUpload + widget.model.image)
            : Image.file(
              _imageFile, 
            fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

This Code when i call nvaigator.pop

```
MaterialButton(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      onPressed: () async {
                        final sign = _sign.currentState;
                        //retrieve image data, do whatever you want with it (send to server, save locally...)
                        final image = await sign.getData();
                        var data = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
                        sign.clear();
                        final encoded = base64.encode(data.buffer.asUint8List());
                        var data2 = data.buffer.asUint8List();
                        Navigator.pop(context, data2);
                        debugPrint("onPressed " + encoded);
                      },
                      child: Text("Save")),
```

i want after draw the signature , result image return to firstscreen and state as _imageFile .

Comment: sorry , please check again my post , i've been edit my post . thanks .

Comment: i'm use example from package flutter_signature_pad , and " var data2 = data.buffer.asUint8List(); " this result image from drawing signature , CMIIW .